# How to replace a regex pattern in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mysql-5.7

I have a table called `myTable` which has a column called `col1`. This column contains data in this format: (1 or 2 digits)(hyphen)(8 digits).

I want to replace all the data in this column and replace everything before hyphen with 4, so this is an example:

```
--------------------------------
|  old values   |  New Values  |
--------------------------------
| 1-654283568  =>  4-654283568 |
| 2-467862833  =>  4-467862833 |
| 8-478934293  =>  4-478934293 |
| 12-573789475 =>  4-573789475 |
| 16-574738575 =>  4-574738575 |
--------------------------------
```

I am using MySQL 5.7.19, I believe `REGEXP_REPLACE` is available in MySQL Version 8+... not sure how this can be achieved?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex; you can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract everything after the hyphen and concatenate `4-` to that:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET col1 = CONCAT('4-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', -1))
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=88f40fc9cce1f68277ba40a2fde27a0d)

This will work regardless of the number of characters after the hyphen.

Comment: To be fair to @scaisEdge who answered this original question you should probably leave their answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your pattern  seem you could avoid regexp

```
update myTable  
set col1  = concat('4-', right(col1,8))
```

or

```
update myTable  
set col1  = concat('4', right(col1,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT( @new_prefix, SUBSTRING(old_value FROM LOCATE('-', old_value)) ) AS new_value
```

---

```
UPDATE sourcetable
SET fieldname = CONCAT( '4', SUBSTRING(fieldname FROM LOCATE('-', fieldname)) )
WHERE LOCATE('-', fieldname)
/* AND another conditions */
```

Comment: @HoomanBahreini *but @new_prefix is not defined here...* ??? You have said "I want to replace all the data in this column and replace everything before hyphen with 4", so `@new_prefix := '4'`.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini `UPDATE` query added. The records which does not contain a dash will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE testing SET val=REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,1,LOCATE('-',val)),'4-');
```

Fiddle here :https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4mU5ctLh8NB9iKSKZF9Ue2/2

Using `LOCATE` to find '-' position then use `SUBSTRING` to get only the front part of the '-'.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your last edit, where you added the tag [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), a solution using a regular expression would be:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET col1 = CONCAT('4-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', -1))
WHERE col1 REGEXP '[0-9]*-'
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ze4xm_-L)

P.S. Do note that you could also have typed `WHERE col1 REGEXP col1`