# How to replace all the digits before hyphen with a new digit using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table called `myTable` which has a column called `col1`. This column contains data in this format: (1 or 2 digits)(hyphen)(5 to 10 digits)(0 or 1 char).

I want to replace all the data in this column and replace everything before hyphen with 4, so this is an example:

```
--------------------------------
|  old values   |  New Values  |
--------------------------------
| 1-6542835    =>  4-6542835   |
| 2-46786283x  =>  4-46786283x |
| 8-478934293  =>  4-478934293 |
| 12-573789    =>  4-573789    |
| 16-5747385z  =>  4-5747385z  |
--------------------------------
```

I am using MySQL 5.7.19, I believe REGEXP_REPLACE is available in MySQL Version 8+... not sure how this can be achieved?

### NOTE:

I just asked [a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558949/how-to-replace-a-regex-pattern-in-mysql/60559004#60559004) question... but then realized that it was a simplified scenario... since that question is already answered, I don't want to edit it, therefore asking a new question.